Weaviate JS/TS client v3 in Next.js: create() not working, insertMany() not working, iterator() not working, delete() not working, etc
Description
I'm using the Weaviate JS/TS client v3.0.8 in a Next.js app v14.2.4. I connect to Weaviate locally via Docker and use Ollama for vectorization.

Problem
However, no Weaviate JS/TS client v3 method is working:

The create() method is not creating a collection.
The insertMany() method is not inserting items in the collection.
The iterator() method is not iterating over the collection items.
The delete() method is not deleting the collection.

For example, in the finally block, the collection Podcasts should be deleted using the delete() method, but right after the deletion, I still see Collection exists 2: true in the terminal output.
Output without comments:
✓ Compiled in 1699ms (1169 modules)
-------------------------
Weaviate connected
Collection: Podcasts
Collection exists 1: true
Collection found
Data inserted
Code executed here
Collection exists 2: true

Output with comments:
 ✓ Compiled in 1699ms (1169 modules)
-------------------------
Weaviate connected
Collection: Podcasts  How can the Podcasts collection be found if I deleted it in the finally block?
Collection exists 1: true  Again, how can the Podcasts collection be found if I deleted it in the finally block?
Collection found  Again, how can the Podcasts collection be found if I deleted it in the finally block?
Data inserted
 I expect here that the inserted item is found if it really was inserted, but it's not.
Code executed here
Collection exists 2: true  How can the Podcasts collection be found if I just deleted it?


Possible causes
There's something fundamentally wrong with my code, as far as I can tell. I see two possible causes:

Maybe I didn't set up the docker-compose.yml file correctly.
Maybe Weaviate JS/TS client v3 doesn't work like I want to use it. I see that Weaviate JS/TS client v3 uses gRPC, which doesn't support browser-based client development, but my page.tsx is not a client-side component:


The gRPC protocol is fast and provides other internal benefits.
Unfortunately, gRPC does not support browser-based client development.
The v3 client uses gRPC to connect to your Weaviate instance. The
client supports Node.js, server-based development. It does not support
browser-based web client development.
To develop a browser-based application, use the v2 client.


Code
page.tsx
import weaviate from "weaviate-client";
import { vectorizer, dataType } from "weaviate-client";

// Define the main function for the Next.js page component
export default async function Home() {
  // Connect to the local Weaviate instance
  const client = await weaviate.connectToLocal();

  if (client) {
    console.log("-------------------------");
    console.log("Weaviate connected");
  }

  // List all collections and log their names
  const listAllCollections = await client.collections.listAll();
  for (const collection of listAllCollections) {
    console.log("Collection:", collection.name);
  }

  try {
    // Check if the "Podcasts" collection exists
    const collectionExists = await client.collections.exists("Podcasts");
    console.log("Collection exists 1:", collectionExists);

    // If the collection does not exist, create it
    if (!collectionExists) {
      const createCollection = await client.collections.create({
        name: "Podcasts",
        vectorizers: vectorizer.text2VecOllama({
          apiEndpoint: "http://host.docker.internal:11434",
          model: "nomic-embed-text",
        }),
        properties: [
          {
            name: "podcast_number",
            dataType: dataType.INT,
          },
          {
            name: "podcast_guest",
            dataType: dataType.TEXT,
          },
          {
            name: "podcast_title",
            dataType: dataType.TEXT,
          },
          {
            name: "podcast_transcription",
            dataType: dataType.TEXT,
          },
        ],
      });

      if (createCollection) {
        console.log("Collection created");
      }
    }

    // Get the "Podcasts" collection
    const getCollection = await client.collections.get("Podcasts");

    if (getCollection) {
      console.log("Collection found");
    }

    // Define a test data entry to be inserted into the collection
    const test = [
      {
        podcast_number: 1,
        podcast_guest: "Guest test",
        podcast_title: "Title test",
        podcast_transcription: "Transcription test",
      },
    ];

    // Insert the test data into the collection
    const insertData = await getCollection.data.insertMany(test);

    if (insertData) {
      console.log("Data inserted");
    }

    // Iterate over the collection and log each item
    const iterator = getCollection.iterator();
    for await (let item of iterator) {
      console.log(item);
    }

    console.log("Code executed here");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    try {
      // Delete the "Podcasts" collection
      const deleteCollection = await client.collections.delete("Podcasts");

      // Check if the collection still exists after deletion
      const collectionExistsAfterDelete = await client.collections.exists(
        "Podcasts"
      );
      console.log("Collection exists 2:", collectionExistsAfterDelete);
    } catch (deleteError) {
      console.error("Error during collection deletion:", deleteError);
    } finally {
      // Close the Weaviate client connection
      client.close();
    }
  }

  // Return the main component structure
  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
      <div>Hello world!</div>
    </main>
  );
}

docker-compose.yml
---
services:
  weaviate:
    command:
    - --host
    - 0.0.0.0
    - --port
    - '8080'
    - --scheme
    - http
    image: cr.weaviate.io/semitechnologies/weaviate:1.25.4
    ports:
    - 8080:8080
    - 50051:50051
    volumes:
    - weaviate_data:/var/lib/weaviate
    restart: on-failure:0
    environment:
      SPELLCHECK_INFERENCE_API: 'http://text-spellcheck:8080'
      QUERY_DEFAULTS_LIMIT: 25
      AUTHENTICATION_ANONYMOUS_ACCESS_ENABLED: 'true'
      PERSISTENCE_DATA_PATH: '/var/lib/weaviate'
      DEFAULT_VECTORIZER_MODULE: 'text2vec-ollama'
      ENABLE_MODULES: 'text2vec-ollama,text-spellcheck,generative-ollama'
      CLUSTER_HOSTNAME: 'node1'
  text-spellcheck:
    image: cr.weaviate.io/semitechnologies/text-spellcheck-model:pyspellchecker-en
  ollama:
    image: ollama/ollama
volumes:
  weaviate_data:
...


Hi!
If you run this code locally thru node, does it work?
Maybe next.js is running this on the client side? Indeed, the GRPC will prevent js/ts code being runned in browser, so this could be the issue here.
